# Android 11 WPA Enterprise

Tags: wi-fi, android-11, wlan

There are a lot of threads about Android 11 and WPA Enterprise, but none of it seems to have a solution for my specific problem.

I'm using a UniFi WLAN infrastructure with a connected FreeRADIUS. Since I updated my phone to Android 11, I can't connect to the network. I read that the issue comes from the disabled "don't validate" option for WiFi in Android. But even if I import the right certificate (I tried to import the CA and the FreeRADIUS server certificate on my phone), I can't connect to the WiFi. I'm prompted to enter a domain on WiFi setup, but I don't really know what to enter there. I tried to enter the CN of my certificate/CA there, but this won't work either.

Here's what my radius is telling me:

```
Tue Aug 31 14:15:09 2021 : ERROR: (165589) eap_ttls: ERROR: TLS Alert read:fatal:unknown CA
Tue Aug 31 14:15:09 2021 : Auth: (165589) Login incorrect (eap_ttls: TLS Alert read:fatal:unknown CA): [anonymous@local.domain/<via Auth-Type = eap>] (from client UAPs port 0 cli MAC
```

Does anybody know how to debug or solve that issue?

Comment: As far as I know for importing certificates on Android 11 there are multiple categories you can import the certificates into - one if as WiFi certificate. Which category did you chose?

Comment: Tried both. WiFi & CA Certificate.